# Is there any difference between Qt's MinGW, Code::Blocks' MinGW and MinGW it self?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, codeblocks

Qt and Code blocks download package have their MinGW compiler. And there's standalone MinGW itself. Is there any difference between them?

Can I use Qt's MinGW to build Code blocks project or vice versa?

Did I need another MinGW if i want to build C++ project without Qt Creator or Code Blocks?

Or, can I just use Qt's or Code Blocks' MinGW without standalone version of MinGW?

Answer (score 3):

Both Qt Creator and CodeBlocks just bundle a version of MinGW (GCC) in their installations for convenience, so that users don't have to install it and configure it manually. In both cases, you can choose to download or install the IDE without installing MinGW (GCC), in which case, you need to configure the IDE to use whatever compiler you want it to use (which not only can be any standalone MinGW/GCC installation, but also any other compiler, including MSVC (Microsoft compiler), ICC (Intel's compiler), or Clang).

[Here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-tool-chains.html) are instructions to configure a custom compiler for Qt Creator. And [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler) are instructions for CodeBlocks.

> Is there any difference between them?

As far as I know, there is no significant difference between them, except for the version, of course. IDEs that are bundled with MinGW-GCC will typically come with one particular (and often a bit older / more stable) version of it. When you install a standalone MinGW-GCC, it can be whatever version you choose. There are differences between versions, but usually not anything that would "break" code, just faster / better compilations or additional advanced features (which are not used by "default" projects in any case).

> Can I use Qt's MinGW to build Code blocks project or vice versa?

I'm pretty sure you can. I don't see any reason why not. Of course, you have to get the configuration right, as per the instructions I linked to above.

> Did I need another MinGW if i want to build C++ project without Qt Creator or Code Blocks?

If you want to build things outside of an IDE that is configured with a particular compiler or installation of MinGW, then you will have to make sure to [setup a few things](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-MinGW-%28Minimalist-Gnu-C/C%2B%2B-Compiler%29-on-Microsoft-Windows). This process is easier when doing a standalone installation of MinGW, but you can also figure out how to take an existing MinGW installation (that came from Qt / CodeBlocks) and make it work under CMD / PowerShell / MSYS, but it's a bit trickier and more unusual.

Comment: Be careful about versions. MinGW comes in SJLJ, SEH, and DWARF-2 favours. Also it may happen that the C++ library changes its class memory layout between versions. So stick to one compiler version, and compile all your libraries with it except pure C libraries, which have a more established ABI. This avoids strange bugs.